# tables = pd.read_html indexerror: list index out of range

Tags: python, pandas, html-parsing

I am trying to get dataframe out of a table from website. I got an error: Indexerror: list index out of range. Please help.

```
import pandas as pd
tables = pd.read_html("http://stat.legalpress.ru/stats/ug/t/11/s/1")
ren=tables[1]
ren
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has only 1 table and sine array/lists are 0-indexed in python you should use `tables[0]` instead of `tables[1]`.

```
import pandas as pd
tables = pd.read_html("http://stat.legalpress.ru/stats/ug/t/11/s/1")
ren=tables[0]
ren
```